# Reverse Multiplication Table

Tags: python, python-2.4

I'm having troubling reversing my multiplication table.

This is what I have so far:

```
def reverseTable(n):
    for row in range(1, n+1):
        print(*("{:3}".format(row*col) for col in range(1, n+1)))
```

But I want to reverse it to:

```
25 20 15 10 5
20 16 12 8 4
15 12 9 6 3
10 8 6 4 2
```

Comment: What output do you get now?

Comment: I get a regular multiplication table.

Comment: I would like to reverse so it decreases instead of increasing

Comment: Indent code by using four spaces (or press the `{}` button) to display it in codeblocks. That way it is easier to read.

Comment: Thank you. This is my first time posting.

Answer (score 3):

You need to reverse your range so it counts backwards. The `range()` function accepts 3 parameters, `range(start, stop, step)` so to count from 10 to 1 you would use `range(10, 0, -1)`

Try this:

```
def reverseTable(n):
    for row in range(n, 0, -1):
        print(*("{:3}".format(row*col) for col in range(n, 0, -1)))
```

Answer (score 2):

```
for row in range(9,0,-1):
    print(end="\t")
    for column in range(9,0,-1):
        print(row*column,end="\t ")
    print()
```

Comment: Whilst this code snippet is welcome, and may provide some help, it would be [greatly improved if it included an explanation](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/114762) of *how* and *why* this solves the problem. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, not just the person asking now!  Please [edit] your answer to add explanation, and give an indication of what limitations and assumptions apply.

Answer (score 2):

reverse multiplication table in python taking value from user

```
num = int(input("enter the number= "))
i=10
while i>=1:
    print(num,"X",i,"=",num*i)
    i= i-1
```

output

```
enter the number= 3
3 X 10 = 30
3 X 9 = 27
3 X 8 = 24
3 X 7 = 21
3 X 6 = 18
3 X 5 = 15
3 X 4 = 12
3 X 3 = 9
3 X 2 = 6
3 X 1 = 3
```

Answer (score 2):

```
num=int(input("enter your table number:   "))
for i in range(10,0,-1):
    print(str(num) + "x" + str(i) + "=" + str(num*i))
```

Answer (score 2):

Here's your answer

```py
num=int(input("Enter the number"))
for i in range (10,0,-1):
  print(f"{num}*{i}={num*i}")
```

Answer (score 1):

```
num = int(input("enter a no.")) 

count = 10 

while count >= 1:
    X = num*count
    print(num, "x", count, "=", X)
    count = count - 1
```

Comment: Please format your code accordingly and describe what it does exactly. If you can provide sample output even more appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

i used this i dont know if it is of any help to you since I am a beginner and have just started learning python

```
    num= int(input("please enter the  number: "))
    n= 11
    for i in range(0,10):
     n -= 1
     print(f"{num} x {n} = {num*n} ")
```